# How to resolve HTTP and HTTPs config in DNS level?

Tags: dns

I have my domain pointed in Cloudflare with SSL. My website runs with HTTPS protocol. The reason i mention them running is this.

I have my blog at blogspot and want to give it custom domain name which google allows. Unfortunately google wont allow HTTPS there. I had created my blog like this in DNS as blog.domain.com which runs as https://blog.domain.com and if i host this subdomain via Github, it opens correctly. The problem is when i use this subdomain in blogger, then there arises conflict and my site goes offline. Where am i mistaking in setting up all this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't enable full or restricted SSL option in cloudflare. Use **flexible SSL** instead. This will setup things correctly.